# Extracting text from complex pdf in Linux

Tags: linux, pdf

As the title says, I would like to be able to extract text from a pdf document.  The documents I want to analyse are time sheets for a sporting event, and is basically what looks like to be a table, formatted as such:

```
A bunch of header info
athlete 1 5.31 (1) 38.24 (2) 57.94 (1) 42.13 120.50
          5.37 (2) 38.66 (2) 58.93 (5) 41.87 119.33
athlete 2 5.52 (5) 38.89 (4) 59.23 (7) 41.16 118.38
          5.43 (4) 38.98 (5) 59.52 (8) 41.61 117.30
```

I've tried to use pdftotext, but I am unable to get it to keep the formatting.    It seems to randomly place page breaks.  For example, I might get the following output:

```
athlete 1 
5.31 (1)
5.37 (2)

38.24 (2)
38.66 (2) 


57.94 (1) 42.13 120.50
58.93 (5) 41.87 119.33

athlete 2
5.52 (5)
5.43 (4) 

38.89 (4)
38.98 (5)

59.23 (7) 41.16
59.52 (8) 41.61

118.38 
117.30
```

Does anyone know how I could extract each line of text separately?   Or at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I should checked the man page for pdftotext.   Using the -layout option does a very good job at preserving the layout as seen in the original pdf document:

```
pdftotext pdfinput.pdf output.txt -layout
```